# Auto disable specific extension when launch visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio

I want to configure different extensions for different projects, for example, enable visual assist for c++ projects, but disable it for c# projects.

I try to export two vssetting files, and run "devenv.exe /Resetting 1.vssetting" or "devenv.exe /Resetting 2.vssetting", but it fails to retain extensions status.

Any one helps me? Thanks very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One hacky method is to modify the **ExtensionManager\EnabledExtensions** list in the registry. For example, for Visual Assist in VS 2015 its registry entry is like this (name is a fixed guid plus version number, path is random):

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ExtensionManager\EnabledExtensions]
"44630d46-96b5-488c-8df926e21db8c1a3,10.9.2102.0"="C:\\Users\\sv\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\VisualStudio\\14.0\\Extensions\\w1vivolz.4tz\\"
```

If you remove this entry, Visual Assist becomes disabled. Put it back and it is enabled again.